# ValueError: Invalid field type <class 'shapely.geometry.polygon.Polygon'> when exporting shp?

Tags: python, shapefile, export, geopandas

I try to export an `shp` from `Python` using `geopandas` with this:

```
#Create a output path for the data
out = r"C:\Users\hhh\Desktop\ge.shp"

## Write those rows into a new Shapefile 
df.to_file(out)
```

and I get this error:

```
ValueError: Invalid field type <class 'shapely.geometry.polygon.Polygon'>
```

The type of the `df` is `geopandas.geodataframe.GeoDataFrame` and I have done some geoprocessing which may be causing errors at the output. Also, it gives an output but when I open it, it shows nothing and the attribute table is also empty.

I checked this with another case by taking a subset from an shp read in python:

```
out = r"C:\Users\hhh\Desktop\hid.shp"

selection = data[0:50]

selection.to_file(out)
```

and it worked.

What can be causing this problem in the first case?

Comment: Can you show the full traceback? And show a sample of the data? (eg `data.head()` and `data.info()`) (or ideally a reproducible example)

Comment: But from the error message: do you have multiple columns with geometry data? Shapefiles can only handle a single geometry column.

Comment: You are correct, I solved it like that but I hadn't inform

Comment: @joris you could answer the question

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Shapefiles have some limitations, including:

- They cannot have multiple columns with geometry data
- The geometries cannot contains multiple types (so eg both Points and LineStrings)

In both cases you will get errors when trying to write a GeoDataFrame to a shapefile.